# android - Add a ListActivity in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, listactivity

I would like to add a `ListActivity` in `Activity`.

For Example, there's a title and a button on top of the page of the `Activity`, and the `ListActivity` is the main content of the `Activity`.
The button would be able to load different `ListActivity` below.

When swiping left and right, there will be new `Activity`s and new content in the main section.

Swipe left and right to change the full screen, toggle the button to change the content in the main section (the box with shades and the text "ListActivity").

**Edit:** 
Like this image:

[image]

How can I do that?

I've tried to use `Intent`, but it starts a `new Intent` and the content of the `ListActivity` occupies the full screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want that? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: you can use a listview as one of the views in the activity instead of using listactivity

Comment: The `ListActivity` is dynamically changed, and the `Activity` is kind of like a "static background" with a button the change the content of the `ListActivity` below.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I've added an image, please take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara: I am using viewPager and the samples/libraries from here: 
- android-viewflow: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow 
- Android-ViewPagerIndicator: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    />
</LinearLayout>



public class StockList extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };  

        // First paramenter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                android.R.id.text1, values);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do it like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);

String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

for more detail check [Android ListView and ListActivity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)